# Macro, Capturar MOUSE e TECLADO

Tags: java

Preciso fazer um macro, capturando mouse e teclado.
Como devo proceder em JAVA ?
preciso de alguma API específica ?

Comment: Precisa mesmo ser em Java? Java é uma linguagem de alto nível, e seu propósito está longe de tratar comunicação com hardware, com certeza precisará de alguma biblioteca específico para o SO em questão. Se você estiver usando Windows e quiser **controlar** mouse e teclado pode usar [**AutoIt**](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/), entretanto acredito que não conseguirá **capturar**.

Comment: O que queres dizer com macro? queres saber todos os movimentos do rato durante um período de tempo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se entendi bem, a ideia de fazer uma Macro seria para automatizar uma tarefa, como se fosse um usuário utilizando o computador.

A API do Java disponibiliza a classe [`Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) para isso. Ela contém métodos que disparam eventos simples como `mouseMove`, `mousePress` e `keyPress`.

Para automação de tarefas simples ela deve funcionar bem. Porém, a documentação alerta que em alguns sistemas podem ser necessárias permissões especiais para funcionar.

Não conheço muito bem essa API, então não posso adiantar quais são as limitações e problemas que podem ocorrer.

Se precisar de algo mais elaborado pode tentar uma API de terceiros, como a [jNativeHook](https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/), que fornece uma API Java fazendo interface com métodos nativos da API do Sistema Operacional. Na verdade, a ideia é a mesma da classe `Robot`, mas eles prometem mais funcionalidades.

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Só para completar a resposta do @utluiz

Alguns exemplos práticos do uso dessas funções:

*Rato descontrolado anda aleatoriamente pelo ecra:*

```
public static  void movemouse(){
        Robot robot = null;
        try {
            robot = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        Random random = new Random();
        while (stop<=30) {
            robot.mouseMove(random.nextInt(500), random.nextInt(500));
            stop++;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }                
        }               
    }
```

*Programa que desliga o computador(possivelmente deve ter de alterar os valores devido a resolução)*

```
public static  void desligaPc(){
    Robot robot = null;
    try {
        robot = new Robot();
    } catch (AWTException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

        robot.mouseMove(0, 800);
        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        robot.mouseMove(300, 700);
        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);            
    }    
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pelos exemplos!